Why is my Feh background image resolution mismatch with i3 on Ubuntu?
On my 5120x1440 resolution screen, I have the following strange issue. I am running i3 on Ubuntu.
On the initial load (from log-in), my Feh background seems to think that the screen is 3840x1080 resolution and is tiling my wallpaper.

However, once I reload i3 (Mod+Shift+R), it rights itself as shown in the image.

This is what my i3 config looks like:
exec_always --no-startup-id xrandr --output DP-4 --mode 5120x1440 --rate 60
exec_always --no-startup-id $HOME/.config/polybar/launch.sh --forest
exec_always --no-startup-id feh --bg-max ~/Pictures/wallpapers/space_01.jpg

I'm not sure if this is an xrandr problem or otherwise because the rest of the screen is fine and everything is in the correct resolution/settings. As you can see, even Polybar is in the right place and in the right size.
